# expression as the result of calling a function in C++

Tags: c++, expression, rvalue

How does result of function call can be an expression?
I am reading this article - http://eel.is/c++draft/expr
and it is written there that

> An expression is an xvalue if it is the result of calling a function, whether implicitly or explicitly, whose return type is an rvalue reference to object type

I don't understand how does an expression can be a result of function call.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two examples.

```
const auto someValue = 43 * otherValue;
const auto someOther = func();
```

In both cases, the right hand side of the assignent is an expression. In the first case, it's an integer multiplication. In the second call, it's a function call. Let's be as clear as possible: the expression is not the result of calling a function -- instead, `func()` *is* an expression.

Let's imagine the signature of this function call is

```
struct Obj { /* ... */ };

Obj&& func();
```

Here, the return type is an rvalue reference of object type. This is meant by the wording in the standard. And in the above case, the expression `func()` is an *xvalue* (an "eXpiring value").

Comment: But why then it is not written that the function call which returns rvalue reference is xvalue instead of the result of the function call?

Comment: I think the function call itself is not an xvalue, but an expression - and the value category of this expression is an xvalue.

Comment: I mean that there is written that the result of function call is xvalue , but why not function call in expression itself?